# UI button listener AddListener not working in a loop

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I've got problem with UI listener. I try to assign click listener to the method in for loop for UI, but every time I've got last option selected.

```
public Button[] options;

void Start () 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
    {
        options[i].onClick.AddListener(()=> {OptionPressed(i);});
    }
}

private void OptionPressed(int i)
{
    print (i);
}
```

It's always print 3. My question is why? and also why 3 while there is only 3 buttons, so it should be 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It prints `3` because you're not boxing the value of `i`, it's value is getting re-written each time it iterates.
To fix this try doing something like this :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < options.Length; ++i )
{
    int j = i;
    options[i].onClick.AddListener( () => { OptionPressed(j); } );
}
```

[Check the difference](http://rextester.com/XJEQM60220)

Comment: This question has been asked so many times that it should now be closed as a duplicate unless there is another problem in the script from the question.

Comment: Thanks @m.rogalski , I should think about it.