# 2 Dynamic Buttons, 1 Event Handler. How to determine who clicked the event?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic

I'm trying to determine from my 2 dynamic buttons who click the event handler.

How i create my 2 dynamic buttons at Form load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        for (int q = 0; q < 2; q++)
        {
            Point newLoc = new Point(a, b);              
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3 - 1; i++)
            {
                buttonArray[i] = new Button();
                buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(95, 80);
                buttonArray[i].Name = "btn" + q;
                buttonArray[i].Text = "btn" + q;
                buttonArray[i].Click += newButton;
                buttonArray[i].Location = newLoc;
                a = a + 10;
                if (a > 300)
                {
                    b = b + 100;
                    a = 1;
                }
                this.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);
            }
        }                 
    }
```

The Event I'm trying to call

```
   void newButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == "btn1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btn1");          
        }

        if (sender == "btn2")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btn2");
        }
    }
```

It can call the event handler if I do not add the IF statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `object sender` to a `Button`and then test against the `Name` property:

```
void newButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    // btn could be null if the event handler would be 
    // also triggered by other controls e.g. a label
    if(btn != null) 
    {
        if (btn.Name == "btn1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btn1");          
        }

        if (btn.Name == "btn2")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btn2");
        }
    }
}
```

In C# 7.0 you can simplify that call:

```
void newButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is Button btn) 
    {
        if (btn.Name == "btn1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btn1");          
        }

        if (btn.Name == "btn2")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btn2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is `if(btn == btn1)`. For `switch/case` using `string` is a good idea, though I'd use `switch(btn.Name) { case btn1.Name: ...` (or `nameof`), because string literals are immune to refactor.

Comment: @Sinatr The problem is, that there is no `btn1` reference

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.
**One :**

```
buttonArray[i].Name = "btn" + q;
buttonArray[i].Text = "btn" + q;
```

You should create and pass new value for each button :

```
int temp = q;
buttonArray[i].Name = "btn" + temp;
buttonArray[i].Text = "btn" + temp;
```

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635608/ui-button-listener-addlistener-not-working-in-a-loop/43635699#43635699)

**Two :**

```
if (sender == "btn1")
{
    MessageBox.Show("btn1");          
}
```

You're comparing a `Button` object to a `string`. What you want to do is to check if your `sender` is `Button` at first and then check it's `Name` property.

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
if(btn != null)
{
    if (btn.Name == "btn1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("btn1");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it with **One**? I don't get it.

Comment: Added link to another answer with some more details about boxing the value.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that problem. Nevertheless, your code wont solve the problem, since you still attach `q` instead of `temp`. Correct code should be  int temp = q; 
buttonArray[i].Name = "btn" + temp; 
buttonArray[i].Text = "btn" + temp;' 
then

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I am with @RomanoZumbé, where do you see closures here to have **One**?